# Can not create file using php

Tags: 14.04, php, sftp

I want to create new file into

```
/etc/freeradius
```

I try to run PHP script,but the file not created

This is my code:

```php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Net/SFTP.php');
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('localhost');
if (!$sftp->login('muhammad', 'Kaynetc0m')) {
exit('Login Failed');
}
$sftp->chdir( '/etc/freeradius' );
$sftp->put("sql.conf", $txt,NET_SFTP_RESUME);
```

I want to append text to sql.conf file into freeradius directory

this is the output:

```
 ls -l /etc/freeradius/sql.conf
-rw-r----- 1 muhammad freerad 12549 Eyl 25 15:27 /etc/freeradius/sql.conf
```

In other hands when I execute this code on other path and file it executed nice

Comment: Is this code ran from within freeradius?

Comment: Possible user Muhammad should have appropriate rights to modify directory /etc/freeradius/  Cause when you adding file to directory - you modifying directory; when you append to file via ftp - you are deleting file and creating new one with new content.

Comment: How do you run the php script? If you call it from a webserver (e.g. apache) than not you but the server needs acces to this file (`chown www-data:freerad /etc/freeradius/sql.conf`)